# Custom scrollbar in a Chrome App

Tags: css, google-chrome, scrollbar, google-chrome-app, blink

I'd like to customize the scrollbar of my Chrome App with the CSS rule #2:

```
section { overflow: auto }
section::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 5px ;
}
```

Unfortunately, with the second rule, Chrome won't display the scrollbar.
Without that second rule the default scrollbar is displayed as expected.

Is it a normal behavior?
I checked the documentation but found nothing on that...

Comment: Does it work if you load the page as a normal page, not in an app?

Comment: @Xan good point: the scrollbar is here but transparent! I've added another rule : ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
 background-color: grey ; 
}
and now it's OK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it's not visible until you describe how to show it with `::-webkit-scrollbar-track` and `::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb`

CSSTricks lists this as a *minimal* example:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 12px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3); 
    border-radius: 10px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.5); 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help again. NB: the ::webkit-scrollbar-track is useful but optional.